# I'm having trouble running the python-telegram-bot Library sample code

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to use the example codes from the repository's beginners guide and the ready-made examples:
[wiki](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot)&
[examples](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples)

I can't run them because of some classes that can't be imported. I'm using Visual Studio and when debugging, find the following error

```
from telegram.ext import (
    Application,
    CallbackContext,
    CommandHandler,
    ConversationHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    filters,
)
```

gives this error

```
cannot import name 'Application' from 'telegram.ext'
```

Was it my mistake? I uninstalled and installed using pip, the error keeps showing up

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't installed it correctly .

try installing it with **setup.py** in order to do that just follow these steps

1- `git clone "repository link"`

2-  `cd python-telegram-bot`

3- `py setup.py install`  or `python setup.py install`

Your code has no problem.
if you encountered and error while doing this please do comment.

Comment: I got it using version v20 (pre-release) using pip. 'pip install python-telegram-bot --pre'. Strange how installing the stable version using pip should technically be the most stable and not give errors. Must be some version bug

Answer (score 0):

You are installing the alpha version which has a lot of changes.
To fix this issue:

1. Uninstall PTB v20
2. Install latest PTB stable version (which is version 13) using: `pip install python-telegram-bot`
3. use [this version of documentation](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/v13.x-wiki/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot) for a tutorial on how to write your first bot.